# Adding condition when counting NA value by a group

Tags: r

I am counting row-based Na values according to col1 variable in the data set. I want to add a condition to this query:

When calculating the number of NA,
For col2 = a and b, also look at col4 column, for col2 = c, do not look at col4 column

```
# creating a dataframe
data_frame <- data.frame(col1 = sample(6:9, 9 , replace = TRUE),
                        col2 = letters[1:3],
                        col3 = c(1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,2,NA,2),
                        col4 = c(1,4,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,2))
  

data_frame = data_frame %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(Count_NA = sum(is.na(cur_data()))) %>%
   ungroup

#print (data_frame)

data_frame %>% group_by(col1) %>%
   summarize(Sum_Count_NA=sum(Count_NA))
```

The output I want is;

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | Count_NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | a | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | b | NA | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | c | NA | NA | 2 |
| 7 | a | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | b | NA | NA | 2 |
| 8 | c | NA | NA | 2 |
| 8 | a | 2 | NA | 1 |
| 8 | b | NA | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | c | 2 | 2 | 0 |

After adding the condition, the output I want is;
Counting Na in col4 for col2 = c

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | Count_NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | a | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | b | NA | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | c | NA | NA | 1 |
| 7 | a | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | b | NA | NA | 2 |
| 8 | c | NA | NA | 1 |
| 8 | a | 2 | NA | 1 |
| 8 | b | NA | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | c | 2 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: Please provide the output you expect from your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is also to `replace` the NA elements in the 'col4' with non-NA when 'col2' is 'c' and then do the `rowSums` on the logical matrix

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame %>% 
   mutate(Count_Na = rowSums(is.na(cbind(col3, replace(col4, col2 == 'c', 999)))))
```

-output

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4 Count_Na
1    7    a    1    1        0
2    9    b   NA    4        1
3    9    c   NA   NA        1
4    7    a    1    1        0
5    7    b   NA   NA        2
6    7    c   NA   NA        1
7    7    a    2   NA        1
8    9    b   NA    1        1
9    7    c    2    2        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```r
library(dplyr)
data_frame %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(is.na(select(., contains("col3")))) + (col2 == "c" & is.na(col4)))

  col1 col2 col3 col4 sum
1    8    a    1    1   0
2    6    b   NA    4   1
3    9    c   NA   NA   2
4    8    a    1    1   0
5    7    b   NA   NA   1
6    7    c   NA   NA   2
7    7    a    2   NA   0
8    9    b   NA    1   1
9    7    c    2    2   0
```

**data**

```
data_frame <- structure(list(col1 = c(8L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L), 
    col2 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), col3 = c(1, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 2), col4 = c(1, 4, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I have multiple columns
```sum = sum(is.na(col3))```
I can't enter each manually like this

Comment: See edited answer.